# Use nginx as proxy to a sites.google.com site

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm trying to create a proxy_pass to a sites.google.com site. It works.. kinda. The site appears somewhat different when I access it through the nginx proxy.

My configuration:

```
location /gtis {
    proxy_set_header HOST sites.google.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass https://sites.google.com/site/grupotisociedade/;
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```

What can be wrong?

(broken) site through proxy: [Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYtCs.png)

(correct) site: [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDbZ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the resources (images, css, js) will be on a different domain, ie not sites.google.com. Use something like your web browser tools or [Web Page Test](http://webpagetest.org/) to work out which resources are working and which aren't, a little bit of simple problem solving should work it out. If not you'll need to post actual URLs for us to look at.

Comment: There are different domains for different resources indeed. Domains like ssl.gstatic.com and static.doubleclick.net. I need to have a proxy_set_header HOST for each of these domains?

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to be pretty complex. Can I ask why you're trying to do this, what your business aim is? There might be a better way.

Comment: I gave up and created a simple redirect instead. Thanks anyway!